# Passing parameter to XMLHttpRequest eventListener function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs application with a file upload screen.

In order to monitor progress of file upload, i have registered 'progress' event handler as follows:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
```

My Function:

```
  function uploadProgress(evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                $scope.data.progress[0] = evt.loaded;
            } else {
                $scope.data.progress = 0;
            }
        })
    }
```

I need to pass one more parameter to uploadProgress method.
How can i achieve that?

Essentially an extra parameter say 'i' like this:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress(i), false);
```

Comment: You mean like calling `uploadProgress(i, evt)` instead of `uploadProgress(evt)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not Angular-specific.

You can use standard JS's **[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**:

```
function uploadProgress(i, evt) {
    ...

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress.bind(null, i), false);
```

---

You can use Angular's **[`angular.bind()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind)**:

```
function uploadProgress(i, evt) {
    ...

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", angular.bind(null, uploadProgress, i), false);
```

---

Finally, you could also use a plain old **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)** (it is more code, but has the benefit of allowing you to specify arbitrary argument order):

```
function uploadProgress(evt, i) {
    ...

var j = i;   // because `i` might have changed by the time 
             // our callback is called, we need the current value
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    uploadProgress(evt, j);
}, false);
```